# User copied the text of an old SO question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, plagiarism

I just answered an question and later noticied that he just copied the question text from an 5yr old question (which I used as a refference to answer his question). The title is different, the question is exactly the same.

[His question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32136317/listview-that-the-user-can-scroll-around-before-returning-to-the-previous-screen) vs. the [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014089/maintain-save-restore-scroll-position-when-returning-to-a-listview).

Should I just flag it as duplicate and close it, since the user probably knows the answer..?

Comment: Flag it for plagiarism using a custom mod flag.

Comment: It's been deleted. BTW shouldn't this be on SO Meta?

Comment: cross-site related: [this 1](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269315/changes-to-discourage-plagiarism)  and [this 2](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289123/does-so-detect-plagiarism)